# Run coverage from visual studio and from command line get different result, how to correct it?

Tags: nunit, code-coverage, dotcover, nunit-console

I have a project with unit test, when I right click project and run from visual studio,  I got 100% coverage.  Please see attachment coveargeA.jpg

The method is CleanUpInProcessExperiments.
[image]

but when I run it with command line, then I got 0% coverage, see attachment coverageB.jpg.  How can I match command line with directly run from visual studio.  in fact, I have few methods other than this one has similar issue  Really appreciate for any help.

[image]

Here is the command line I used:

C:\Users\yanghx14\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Installations\dotCover04\dotCover.exe cover /TargetExecutable="C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe"  /TargetWorkingDir=C:\xxx\ExpMgmt.Tests\bin\Release /TargetArguments="C:\xxx\ExpMgmt.Tests\bin\Release\ExpMgmt.Tests.dll /framework=4.0 /xml=C:\xxx\ExpMgmt.Tests\bin\Release\ExpMgmt.Tests.dll-results.xml /timeout=20000 /noshadow=true" /Output=c:\xxx\3.dcvr

Comment: Thanks to make the image displayed.

Comment: Hi Hesper, Did you resolve this? I am also getting the same result.